# Sencha Touch 2 change event in selectfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Code:

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
id: 'selectType',                           
cls: 'combobox',                            
store: 'ProvidersType',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
listeners: {                                
change: function(field, value) {
    alert(111);
}
}
```

I have "111" alert after application load, not only when selecting new option in selectfield. Also I have this alert after using setStore or setValue or updateOptions methods... It's very bad because I'm loading options for selectfield from json, and always have an error, because parameters for json request I'm taking from current selected selectfield value... Any ideas how to avoid this behavior and make it works normally like in jQuery?

**EDITED:**

Hm, it works fine with static options, but works bad if I'm loading options from store...

This code works good and I have alert only on select change:

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
                id: 'selectType',                           
                cls: 'combobox',                            
                options: [
                    {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
                    {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
                    {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
                ],
                listeners: {                                
                    change: function(field, value) {
                        alert(111);                         
                    }
```

But if I'm connecting options from store I have alert right away application load:

```
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        id: 'selectType',                           
                        cls: 'combobox',                            
                        store: 'ProvidersType',
                        displayField: 'name',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        listeners: {                                
                            change: function(field, value) {
                                alert(111);

                            }
                        }
```

Store is:

```
Ext.define('Providers.store.ProvidersType', {    
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model: 'Providers.model.Provider',
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url : 'http://example.dk/providers/service.php',
        extraParams: {
            action: 'provider_types',
            username: 'test2',
            callback: '?',                      
            format: 'json'          
        },          
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'providers'
        }
    },      
    autoLoad: true

}
});
```

Comment: Explain your question neatly. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @roadRunner I want to see "111" alert only on SELECT CHANGE but not on application load or on page refresh.

Comment: Can you post your entire code? From the above code, it seems that you shouldn't get the pop up on application start up ...

Comment: @roadRunner I'm sorry, this situation appears when I'm loading options from store, please see edited question with code samples

Comment: @roadRunner I found a reason, it because property autoLoad is true in my store. Change event firing when data loading from store...

Comment: ok, then please close this question.